# The Horizontal ViewPager Wont work the same time as my VerticalView Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I basically have everything set up already and I don't why it's not working. The only problem I have is that the Vertical won't work when I set it up together. Look at the code down below.

My Main Acitvity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //HorizontalViewPagerAdapter
    View background = findViewById(R.id.am_background_view);
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.am_view_pager);
    HorizontalViewPagerAdapter adapter = new HorizontalViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

My Controller Fragment

```
public class ControllerFragment extends Fragment {

public static ControllerFragment create() {
    return new ControllerFragment();
}

VerticalViewPager verticalViewPager;
VerticalViewPagerAdapter verticalPageAdapter;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical, null);
    verticalViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.am_scrollView);
    verticalPageAdapter = new VerticalViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    verticalViewPager.setAdapter(verticalPageAdapter);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical, null);
}

public class VerticalViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public VerticalViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return SettingsFragment.create();
            case 1:
                return EmptyFragment.create();
            case 2:
                return ExtrasFragment.create();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

}

This is my HorizontalAdapter

```
public class HorizontalViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public HorizontalViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return ChatFragment.create();
        case 1:
            return ControllerFragment.create();
        case 2:
            return StoryFragment.create();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

Its like the whole code is completely ignoring the VerticalView Pager because it doesnt show at all in my app and its completely the same as a normal ViewPager

Comment: When you say vertical view pager, do you mean something that scrolls up and down?

Comment: Yes! I have everything set up I just don't know why they are not going together its either vertical slides or horizontal slides only

Comment: Could you share your project? It'll be easier to see what's going wrong that way.

Comment: I have two adapters one for vertical and one for horizontal sliders public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return ChatFragment.create();
            case 1:
                return EmptyFragment.create();
            case 2:
                return StoryFragment.create();
        }
        return null;
    } This is my vertical adapter and myhorizontaloneisthe same

Comment: That does not help. I'm sorry. If you could share a `GitHub` or some other link of your project (if you are allowed to), it would be helpful.

Comment: I dont have it on github atm its fine thanks anyways

Comment: A simple zip of the project on Google Drive will also work, because the code posted here doesn't seem to be wrong and one will have to run a debugger to understand why you're not getting the desired result.

Comment: How do I set this up?

Comment: @KritstoferH Create a zip of your project and upload it to Google Drive. Be sure to remove all of the `build` folders, the `gradle` folder, the `gradlew` files and `local.properties`. Once uploaded, update your question with the link.

Comment: updated! check it out

Comment: Just got to your code. SO do you want 2 `ViewPager`, or just one which scrolls everywhere?

Comment: I want a viewPager with 3 pages and a vertical ViewPager also with 3 pages but the middle page is the same middle page as the Viewpagers middle page. So in total 5 pages

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to achieve. I changed the code a bit and got [this](https://streamable.com/e93qd). I'll add the answer if this is what you want.

Comment: kinda like that but do you know snapchat? where you got the camera in the middle as a whole page. then when you swipe left its chats snap then swipe right its stories snap when you swipe down you get discovery page and when you swipe down you get a map. I basically just want those swiping features

Comment: Alright. Got it. I haven't used Snapchat in ages, so I don't know how it works now. I understood what you want in a nutshell. One last thing, do you need the up/down swiping on all the pages of the right/left `ViewPager` or just the middle one?

Comment: just the middle one . Thanks alot for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

Having understood what you want to achieve, here's how you'd achieve it!

There are 6 fragments in total. [image: explanation image]

1. Home
2. Left
3. Right
4. Top
5. Botton
6. Controller

## Update

The previous method overrides and prevents horizontal gestures from being captured. I've searched a bit and found an alternative.

First of all, you need a different vertical pager library. I tried the one [here](https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager/blob/master/src/com/grantlandchew/view/VerticalPager.java) and it works perfectly.

So what you wanna do is, get that java file on your project and change your controller's XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<c.kristofer.jax2.VerticalPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/am_scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/top"
        class="c.kristofer.jax2.Fragments.SettingsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home"
        class="c.kristofer.jax2.Fragments.HomeFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        class="c.kristofer.jax2.Fragments.SettingsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</c.kristofer.jax2.VerticalPager>
```

This `ViewPager` does not take an adapter, rather it takes `<fragment>` tags for its child views. The Controller's java code will also change a bit

```
VerticalPager verticalViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.am_scrollView);
verticalViewPager.snapToPage(1);
```

The result can be seen [here](https://streamable.com/t27v2). You can play around with the code and see what suits you best.

#### Previous Method

The activity will have one of the `ViewPager`s, either the Horizontal one or the Vertical one. The middle fragment of that `ViewPager` will be the Controller. Controller will be responsible for the second `ViewPager`. The middle fragment of this `ViewPager` will be Home.

This way, you will have 2 degrees of freedom from the Activity, and 2 degrees of freedom from the Controller.

Comment: Similar to how you setup the first `ViewPager` in the activity, except now it's in a fragment. The `ControllerFragment` will be loaded by the first `ViewPager`

Comment: Oh I tried that already I dont know why it doesnt work with my code ima update question please check what I did wrong

Comment: If I swipe on the top left it opens the left side and when I swipe on the bottom right it opens right side but when I swipe bottom left it won't open left side and if I swipe top right it wont open the right side.  If I swipe up it opens the right side and if I swipe down it opens the left side

Comment: I cant do it wont be able to understand Im new to coding

Comment: Hey from your previous method! I finnaly fixed the random swiping by using another vertical View pager [link](https://github.com/rharter/ViewPager-Android) but the problem I have now is that the Verticalviewpager wont work with the Horizontal View Pager

Comment: Updated my question pls help me out!

Comment: One of the `ViewPagers` won't let the other pager detect the gestures. That is a problem with the previous method. Try the different method I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I dont understand how to write the  Controllers java code. I really dont know how to code I kind of just take things from other people and combine them together. So if you can go deeper I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The XML is for `ControllerFragment`'s layout. Put it there. And in the java code, there's a method called `onViewCreated` which you have to override and put the Java code there. That's all.

Comment: .snaptopage is invalid im not sure why and did you mean onCreateView?

Comment: Use the new `ViewPager` I mentioned in the answer. You need to copy that into your project and use it.

Comment: Is there a way I can just have the middle fragment detect both gestures?